# How to remove credit card number from order confirmation email?

Tags: email, ce-1.8.1.0, payment

I use magento 1.8.1.0.
How can I remove

Credit Card Number:
**** **** **** 1234

this part from order confirmation email?

Comment: which payment gateway,you have using?

Comment: Stripe. I use an extension by TemplateTag, Better to ask the developer?
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/stripe-3.html

Comment: hi go to your module Block folder,There define  are defiene template mean .phtml file

Comment: I don't see .phtml file in Block folder of the extension.

Comment: please check at Model folder,there may some php file where .phtml is written

Comment: I see public function getCcNumber() part in Payment.php . But wouldn't it break any function if I remove this part?

Comment: Tried looking at the templates under System=>Transactional Email? Usually, emails don't require code mangling to fix what displays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution.
Go to detault.phtml under app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/payment/info

and remove

```
<?php if ($_specificInfo = $this->getSpecificInformation()):?>
<table>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($_specificInfo as $_label => $_value):?>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_label)?>:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo nl2br(implode($this->getValueAsArray($_value, true), "\n"))?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php endif;?>
```